# selenium webdriver chrome- "bound method Service"

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to pass an url and get the data using beautifulsoup, but i am resulting in the following error. i dont have any clue what this error is about. i have read some stackoverflow questions but i am unable to find a perfect solution. Please help me. Below is the code and the error.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os, time, csv, datetime
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import threading
import multiprocessing
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import openpyxl
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "https://abcdefgh.com"
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html5lib")
a = soup.find_all("table", class_="readonlydisplaytable")
for b in a:
    c = b.find_all("tr", class_="readonlydisplayfield")
    for d in c:
        if "Super#" in d.get_text():
            e = d.find("td", class_="readonlydisplayfielddata")
            print(e.get_text())
```

Error:

```
C:\Users\mpk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe C:/Users/mpk/Documents/Python/excel.py
Exception ignored in: <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.chrome.service.Service object at 0x004BB330>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mpk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 173, in __del__
  File "C:\Users\mpk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 149, in stop
  File "C:\Users\mpk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 120, in send_remote_shutdown_command
ImportError: sys.meta_path is None, Python is likely shutting down

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Pass the Chromedriver executable path where you are calling the chrome driver method.

Comment: Thanks for answering bad_deadpool, but i am unable to get what i need to do exactly. Could you please be more elaborate what i should do. I am a newbie to python thats y. thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem when running selenium in an AWS lambda server. I am not really sure why it throws the error because on my laptop it works fine, it's just running it in the server that is the problem. It might be something to do with the program terminating with the webdriver still going.

The following solved the problem for me:

At the end of your script before the program terminates, write:

`driver.quit()`

This closes the browser and as I say, fixed it for me. Hope it works for you too!